# Sun Tube glass replacement, manufacturers

Tags: roof

I've got two sun tubes on my roof (pictured, sizes are 14" and 28") that were installed around 1997.

The plastic domes are starting to look worse for wear with cracks and chips and I'm hoping to replace them.

I've looked all over them to see if I can figure out who made them to find replacement parts but no luck.

Anyone have any idea what brand they might be or have suggestions on replacements? Id rather not replace the whole thing. [image: Sun Tube exterior]

[image: Sun Tube another angle]

Comment: Checked out the videos on how to make them?